# If cell A contains NAME AND Cell b Contains YES then Cell C = 1

Tags: excel

I am struggling to visualize any of the solutions I have read that may be relevant to my question. I think this is a pretty straight forward question and hope it wont be too vexing for you experts.

I have a spreadsheet with names in column `A` and yes or no in Column `B`.

I want to check column `A` for name and column b for yes and then if both values are there I want to add 1 to cell `C`.

This will add 1 to cell for every time the criteria is met in both cells in both columns.

Comment: When you say that cell A contains `NAME` is that the text `NAME` or ca it be any name (i.e. a non-blank cell)? Is there only one cell in column C to add values or should the formula put 1 (and additional 1 for subsequent cells) for each row satisfying the condition?

Answer (score 0):

I think a countifs function will solve your problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps!